# Change variable in println

Tags: java, printf

Can I calculate and print sum in string println without creating new variable? Something like this
System.out.println("Hello world " + "value+1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to wrap the value and the added number in to parentheses, otherwise it will concatenate them like they were string characters. Loose the quotetions around value.

```
System.out.println("Hello world" + (value +1));
```

if you actually want quotetions around the value, you need to escape the extra quotetions with the \ char.

```
System.out.println("Hello world" + "\"(value +1)\"");;
```

And if you want to add numbers without concatenation you can use the String.format

```
System.out.println(String.format("Hello world %d", value +1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

`System.out.println("Hello world " + (variable + 1));`